How can I access the API through developer tools in the fastest and easiest way?
How can I access the API through developer tools in the fastest and easiest way?
I can't find a good explanation that makes me reach this interface quickly
I can't find a good explanation that makes me reach this interface quickly
I want to do this through developer administrations

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It is not quite clear to me what your question is.

How can I access the API through developer tools in the fastest and easiest way?

If developer tools means any software a developer might use then there are a loot of options. I like intellij-http-client to connect and to test an api.
I first thought you mean the developer tools that are built into many browsers.
Given an API for example https://httpbin.org/#/Response_formats/get_json you can create a javascript function and paste it into the devtools console.
There is also the sources tab where you can store js files on your local machine.
This code get data from httpbin.org
function LoadDataFromHttpBin()
{        

    const url = 'https://httpbin.org/json';
    
    // Sending a GET request that only accepts JSON
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        // Handle HTTP errors
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
      }
      // Ensure the response is JSON
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      // write the json content to the console
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle errors 
      console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
    });
}

You can paste the code above into the console and then can call / use it by simply entering LoadDataFromHttpBin()

